# WHY does this simple c++ code not compile?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>    
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    cout << rand() << endl ; 
    return 0; 
}
```

error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in test-c5b4b5.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in test-c5b4b5.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::put(char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in test-c5b4b5.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::flush()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in test-c5b4b5.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)", referenced from:
      _main in test-c5b4b5.o
  "std::__1::cout", referenced from:
      _main in test-c5b4b5.o
  "std::__1::ctype<char>::id", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in test-c5b4b5.o
  "std::__1::locale::~locale()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in test-c5b4b5.o
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in test-c5b4b5.o
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in test-c5b4b5.o
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in test-c5b4b5.o
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in test-c5b4b5.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Does the error still happen if you remove the body of `main`.

Comment: Does a *hello world* compile?  If not then it looks like your compiler is fubar'd

Comment: @user985030, clang, it's written in the error message

Comment: Are you using the command `clang` or `clang++` when building? There is a difference when linking.

Comment: That's not a compilation error, that's a linker error. You need to give more details (e.g. the command you use to build the program, and version). I put very good odds that you compiled it in a way that the linker thought it was building a C program, not a C++ program.

Comment: update: must be because of the cost line. If I comment this line out it compiles. If I comment everything else out and only leave in the cout line, it does not compile

Comment: may need the .h as in <cstdilb.h>

Comment: @Gregg it is `<cstdlib>` or `<stdlib.h>`, never `<cstdilb.h>`

Comment: gcc test.cpp -o test -Wall

this is the command I gave to compile the program

Comment: Try `g++` instead of `gcc`.

Comment: @steady_progress Try `clang++ -stdlib=libc++ test.cpp`

Comment: I used g++ now and in worked ....

Comment: Thank you all for your help !

Comment: Was driving me crazy

Answer (score 4):

BLUF: use `g++`, not `gcc`.

This is an example of a *linker* error. Your program compiled fine — e.g. you can see references to the intermediate `*.o` files in the error messages — but it ran into a problem linking things together to make an executable — the linker couldn't find many of the functions needed by the program (e.g. some of the things used in the `iostream` library).

The reason is because the command you used to build the program did it in a way that made the linker try to build it as a *C* program — in particular, it was only linking against the *C* standard library, not the *C++* standard library, which is why it couldn't find those things.

By changing your build command to one that makes the linker aware it's building a C++ program, the errors go away.

I have run into this myself using the gnu compiler collection — while `gcc` is smart enough to *compile* a `*.cpp` program as C++ code, it still tries to link the result as a C program. Thus you need to use the `g++` command to build a C++ program.